# Does anyone step in to fill the holes in your roster?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I deliberately have not named names in the title to avoid spoilers, but in Mass Effect 2 it's possible for

> both Garrus and Tali to die in the course of the endgame.  Couple this with the outcome of the Virmire mission in Mass Effect 1,

and it's very possible that your playable roster could be rather small.

If you're missing these characters, does anybody else step up to fill their holes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no permanent replacement for either. If they die, they die.

There are a few missions where a character who is key to the narrative is replaced, not as a squad member, but in terms of cutscenes and dialogs by another, related individual who you met in Mass Effect 2.

That said, even if both are dead, you're overlooking a squad member. You still have more options than the Survivor, Liara and James.

Comment: Is it just me, or does she look like Scorpio?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Bioware is as Bioware does.

Comment: In light of there being some squad members that weren't known before people got into the game, I've removed that bit from the question. :)