# I broke my Quarian. Do I get a replacement?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone step in to fill the holes in your roster?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53527/does-anyone-step-in-to-fill-the-holes-in-your-roster)

So, I was dumb and messed up the Suicide Mission in ME 2 slightly. Tali ended up.... Slightly dead. I could go back and fix this, but I figure casualties build character.

I know Tali returns as a squad member in ME3, but obviously not if she's dead. If that's the case, is there a replacement availiable? Or will I just always be shorthanded by one Quarian?

Comment: Looks eerily similar to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53527/does-anyone-step-in-to-fill-the-holes-in-your-roster

Comment: Yep. It's a dupe. I missed it. Derp. Close away.

Comment: You killed mai waifu? D= related: What *is* a waifu?

Comment: I imagine this will be a common problem in the coming couple of weeks :)

Comment: @Tristan http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/mai-waifu