# Who replaces Tali?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does anyone step in to fill the holes in your roster?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53527/does-anyone-step-in-to-fill-the-holes-in-your-roster)
>   [I broke my Quarian. Do I get a replacement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53642/i-broke-my-quarian-do-i-get-a-replacement)

In my Mass Effect 2

> Tali is killed

So in 3 she is apparently a squad member, but of course I don't have her.

Who is suppose to replace her in my squad?

Answer (score 1):

Short version: **No one.** Squad members who died in the previous games do not get replacements in your squad.

However,

> [Admiral Shala'Raan vas Tonbay](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Admiral_Shala%27Raan_vas_Tonbay) (first seen in ME2 recusing herself from Tali's hearing) will perform Tali's role in critical plot events (although will not join your team).